# How to receive input from html and use it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Ok so what i am trying to do is on my Chrome Extension, have it where when they click the tab on the top bar there is a input file where you can add a mp3 file to play in the new tab my extension creates. Issue is i dont know how to do it

manifest.json

```
{
  "name":"ImThatGuy's Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Soon will contain verious items",
  "browser_action":
  {
    "default_action": "icon.jpg",
    "default_title": "Title of Extenstion",
    "default_popup": "mypopup.html"
  },
  "icons":
  {
    "128": "icon.jpg"
  },
  "chrome_url_overrides":
  {
    "newtab": "newtab.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Information</title>
  </head>
  <body id="bodyArea">
    <div>
      <h1 id="h1_1">
        Right Now the project is on version 1.0, <br>
        so this is the very basic stage of this project
      </h1>
      <h2 id="h2_2">
        There are things I am currently trying to add to this extension<br>
        Inluding:
        <ul>
          <li>Choice of Song</li>
          <li>Music Spectrum to go with Songs</li>
          <li>Either changing backgrounds or choice of background</li>
          <li>more to come...</li>
        </ul>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="musicChoice">
      <label for="uploadedFile">Drag & drop or select a file to play:</label>
      <input type="file" id="uploadedFile" onchange="getFiles()">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is my popup, as you can tell the input has its own id and js function

visualizer.js

```
var audio = new Audio();

audio.src = 'uploadedFile';
audio.controls = true;
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = false;

var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
var input = document.getElementById("userInput");

window.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);

function initMp3Player()
{
  document.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio);
  context = new AudioContext();
  analyser = context.createAnalyser();
  canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  source.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(context.destination);
  frameLooper();
}

function frameLooper()
{
  window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
  fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#00CCFF';
  bars = 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++)
  {
    bar_x = i * 3;
    bar_width = 2;
    bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2);

    ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
  }
}

function getFiles()
{
  myFile = document.getElementById("uploadedFile");
}
```

this is my javascript function, what i need to happen, is onChange and it starts function get files. i want the function to identify the mp3 file and move it to the top of the js where it says

```
audio.src = 'uploadedFile';
```

that way when you upload the mp3 file, the js function plugs in the file into the script so it plays the audio in the new tab

if i left any information out please inform me before putting my post on hold and id be happy to fill in what i accidently left out.

**Update:** I added the manifest.json code to the question and i have the basics of what i need and that is referencing the input from the html file input type=file, and i have the input referenced in the js file, i just dont know how to plug in the reference to the input to the audio.src in the js.

Comment: What's a `tab on the top bar`? Anyway, you can't transfer non-JSON-ifiable objects between tabs so you'll have to either play in a background/event page or in a content script that's [auto]injected in the new tab.

Comment: the top bar on chrome, the extensions bar on the right hand side, i cant think of the technical term sorry, but so i need to create a background.js and run it through my json file?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Are you asking us to debug already existing code, or write code for you?

Comment: anything else i need to add?

Comment: im asking if you can do a small debug and check if what i have so far will work and if im on the right track, then if you can help me finish the code to work if thats ok